MariaDB, where's the GLOBAL general_log file?
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'general_log%';
+------------------+------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value            |
+------------------+------------------+
| general_log      | ON               |
| general_log_file | ff3b5fbeb27b.log |
+------------------+------------------+

Where can I find this ff3b5fbeb27b.log file?
The https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/query-log.html doc doesn't mention any path it should reside, and my search tell me it's under /var/log/mysql/, yet not for my case:
]> system ls -l /var/log/mysql/
total 0

FTA, my mysql is from the lastest docker image: mariadb:10.5:
$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.25-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

$ uname -rm
6.8.0-1010-azure x86_64


You are not using MySQL, you're using MariaDB 10.5. Please be aware that MariaDB and MySQL are different products, and they are increasingly incompatible. Any answer for one is not necessarily applicable to the other. I've edited your title and tags to better indicate that you are using MariaDB.


By default, the general query log is written to ${hostname}.log in the
datadir directory. However, this can be changed. [...] If it is a
relative path, then the general_log_file is relative to the datadir
directory.
However, the general_log_file system variable can also be an absolute
path.

Full documentation: MariaDB KB - General Query Log
So, in conclusion, since no directory is specified, your general query log is located inside your datadir. In Linux, this defaults to /var/lib/mysql/ but it can of course be at a different location. See the value of your datadir system variable to find out.
